# What is the equivalent to Firebug DOM tab in Chrome Dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am used to using DOM tab to inspect global JS variables that are present on the page in Firebug. What is the equivalent of it in Chrome Developer tools?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Type in `window`, then you will see the `window` object with everything inside it.

p.s: `window` is the "top-most" object in a normal webpage. (Global scope) Since "Chrome Developer Tools" is specifically mentioned, we can safely assume that `window` will always be the global scope.

[image: Developer Tools]
Press `Console`, then enter `window`. Press `enter` and now you can see a list of global variables, such as `$` (jQuery) and `document`.

Comment: p.s 2: You don't need to set a breakpoint in Dev tools to see global variables.

Comment: 1. `window` is not always global JS object. In workers or when inspecting node.js apps Global != window
2. I wrote you can access it from console too.

Comment: @Mohsen, next to `Global` in your picture, it says `DOMWindow`, which means ***under normal condition***, Global === window.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess the real answer is there is no such tab.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called "Properties".

[image]

Comment: So much more helpful for me

Comment: The screenshot shows _the properties of the selected DOM node_, not global variables. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `Scripts` tab in Chrome dev tools.

Also, if you click on the `Console` tab you can actually type in `window.`. You will see a large list of items that are all accessible from the "window" (generally global) scope.

After you find the object or variable you are looking for in the list, you can press `Enter` and Chrome will output the relevant information for your entry.

Answer (score 0):

By setting a breakpoint in first line of your script in **Script** tab you will see all the global variables in **Scope Variables** section in right sidebar. Chrome dev tool will not show variables without a breakpoint but you still can access those from console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following in the Chrome console:

`for(variable in window) {
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
}`